# Binding Context Menu To A View Model Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a context menu that is tied to a button in a datagrid.  I want the context menu items to change based on a list of strings that I have in my view model. When I click the button, nothing shows up.

Here is the xaml I am using, which is in a datagrid:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="..."  Click="Button_Click">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.SelectableDescriptions}">    
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
       </ContextMenu>
       </Button.ContextMenu>        
</Button>
```

Here's the whole DataGrid xaml:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding JobPricings, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedJobPricing, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Description" Width="25*"   >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Description,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="..."  Click="Button_Click">
                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.SelectableDescriptions}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Button.ContextMenu>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Price" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="25*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Binding="{Binding Unit, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="25*"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Currency   " Width="25*" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ComboBox  SelectedValue="{Binding CurrencyID, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Description" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.Currencies}"  ></ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is the property that I am binding the context menu to through my view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> SelectableDescriptions
{
    get
    {
        _selectableDescriptions.Add("One");
        _selectableDescriptions.Add("Two");
        return _selectableDescriptions;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectableDescriptions = value;
    }
}
```

Any ideas of why my list won't show up in the context menu?

Comment: Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Did before but it didn't work.  Anyway, if I am not mistaken, you shouldn't have to with ObservableCollection

Comment: DataContext=JobPricingViewModel ... it's not shown here.  I set it in the code behind.

Comment: when you say 'nothing shows up' do you mean no items, or a number of empty items?

Comment: no items show in the menu.  I can see that there are items in SelectableDescriptions though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the ItemsSource for the ContextMenu in the code behind (even though I really didn't want to use that approach:), which worked

Here's the xaml

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="..."  Name="ellipseButton" Click="ellipseButton_Click">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu >
          <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        </ContextMenu>
     </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
private void ellipseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    button.ContextMenu.ItemsSource = JobPricingViewModel.SelectableDescriptions;
    if (button != null) button.ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
    var placementTarget = sender as Button;
    if (placementTarget != null) placementTarget.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = placementTarget;
    var button1 = sender as Button;
    if (button1 != null)
        button1.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
    var button2 = sender as Button;
    if (button2 != null) button2.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As John says, `ContextMenu` is its own independent window, separated from the button's visual tree, and therefore it doesn't automatically inherit the button's `DataContext`.

However, a ContextMenu does have one link to the object it is placed upon (the button in your case): `PlacementTarget`. By going to the menu's PlacementTarget you find the button, and when you've found the button you can find its DataContext.

So, in xaml you can manually make the ContextMenu inherit the Button's DataContext *by binding its own DataContext to its own `PlacementTarget.DataContext`*, and all other bindings (e.g. for `ItemsSource`) can be written like normal:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="..."  Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectableDescriptions}" >    
            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomePropertyOnItem}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>                            
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>        
</Button>
```

Comment: This might be promising, but when I try it I get the datatype showing up in the context menu.  It might be the <TextBlock Text={Binding}"/> that's doing it.  Not sure

Comment: This won't help in this situation because the menus are on items so the Button DataContext is that item data, not the main UC DataContext that is needed.

Comment: @DJBurb - Sorry, the code was wrong. The `TextBlock` needs to go inside a `DataTemplate` to describe how each menu item should look. I have updated my answer. What it did before was it used the TextBlock as the only menu item, overriding the ItemsSource binding. **Note:** The datatype you saw on the TextBlock must be the datatype that holds the `SelectableDescriptions` list. If it's not, @John's comment is correct.

Comment: Well the SelectableDescriptions is a list of strings, so I am not sure what should go in the binding for <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomePropertyOnItem}" />

Comment: @DJBurb - In that case you just use a binding without a Path (as it was in the first place): `...<DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding}" /></DataTemplate>...`

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not working even with the binding as <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding}" /></DataTemplate>.  I may need to think of another strategy for this thing

Comment: @DJBurb - Could you post some more code? What kind of objects are in the `JobPricings` list? Do each of these objects have a `SelectableDescriptions` list?

Comment: The JobPricing is an entity set.  One of its properties is a property called Description which is a string.  SelectableDescriptions is just a list of strings that can be used in that Description upon selection.  The user has the option of either selecting a SelectableDescription or typing a Description in. Either way if they type a Description or select a SelectableDescription, it will be placed in the current JobPricing.Description property.

Comment: And in this hierarchy of ViewModels and entities, where is the `SelectableDescriptions` list?

Comment: SelectableDescriptions is a direct hit from the viewmodel.  (i.e. JobPricingViewModel.SelectableDescriptions)

Comment: Ok. Remember that each button's (and menu's) DataContext is one JobPricing object (see John's comment above), so the SelectableDescriptions binding in my answer will just fail. If you ever only need one instance of the SelectableDescriptions list, you could make it static, which would make it easier to bind: `<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:JobPricingViewModel.SelectableDescriptions}}" >`. If that's not an option, I can only suggest you have another look at John's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Things like ContextMenu and Popup exist outside the main visual tree and so can't use RelativeSource to walk up to a parent object. In most cases ElementName breaks too. There are various workarounds available depending on the specific situation. I like using inherited attached properties to pass additional data as it doesn't involve changing your VM and stays right in the XAML after you get it set up. Here's a blog post explaining the technique with examples: http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2011/04/26/binding-to-alternate-datacontexts/

Comment: I will need to check this out.  I read through it once, but got confused.  LOL! I'll look again though

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do something like this to your contextmenu, note my assumption is that the way you have the currency set up is working.

```
<ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```